Openssl command works in Linux but not OSX?
This line of code works in Linux, but doesn't in OSX.  What am I missing?
pwd=$(echo "$password_file" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -d -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -salt -pass "pass:$salt_password")

On Linux, it outputs the decrypted text.
On OSX, it just gives openssl usage info, but no error, and no decrypted text.
OpenSSl versions: On OSX:  LibreSSL 2.6.5, on Linux: OpenSSL 3.0.11.
Here's the code in full context:
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

# password_file="$SCRIPT_DIR/test_passfile_2.ssl"
password_file="U2FsdGVkX18RH4KXM5Ldz0Q2ny8RQegoaDPObu50Y6k="
salt_password="salt password"

# Decrypt password file or encrypted passwrod string if provided
if [ -n "$password_file" ]; then
    if [ -f "$password_file" ]; then
        echo "Decrypting password file using salt password..."
        pwd=$(cat "$password_file" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -d -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -salt -pass "pass:$salt_password")
    else
        echo "Decrypting password string using salt password..."
        pwd=$(echo "$password_file" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -a -d -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -salt -pass "pass:$salt_password")
    fi

    esc() {
        printf "%s" "$1" | sed -e "s/'//g"
    }
    
    # utilize the function so that we don't need to quote pwd.
    password=$(esc "${pwd}")
    unset pwd

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error: Failed to decrypt password."
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "Password decrypted successfully."
fi
 
echo $password  # Should output 'test'

Here's the OSX terminal output:
usage: enc -ciphername [-AadePp] [-base64] [-bufsize number] [-debug]
    [-in file] [-iv IV] [-K key] [-k password]
    [-kfile file] [-md digest] [-none] [-nopad] [-nosalt]
    [-out file] [-pass arg] [-S salt] [-salt]

 -A                 Process base64 data on one line (requires -a)
 -a                 Perform base64 encoding/decoding (alias -base64)
 -bufsize size      Specify the buffer size to use for I/O
 -d                 Decrypt the input data
 -debug             Print debugging information
 -e                 Encrypt the input data (default)
 -in file           Input file to read from (default stdin)
 -iv IV             IV to use, specified as a hexadecimal string
 -K key             Key to use, specified as a hexadecimal string
 -md digest         Digest to use to create a key from the passphrase
 -none              Use NULL cipher (no encryption or decryption)
 -nopad             Disable standard block padding
 -out file          Output file to write to (default stdout)
 -P                 Print out the salt, key and IV used, then exit
                      (no encryption or decryption is performed)
 -p                 Print out the salt, key and IV used
 -pass source       Password source
 -S salt            Salt to use, specified as a hexadecimal string
 -salt              Use a salt in the key derivation routines (default)
 -v                 Verbose

Valid ciphername values:

 -aes-128-cbc              -aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha1    -aes-128-cfb            
 -aes-128-cfb1             -aes-128-cfb8             -aes-128-ctr            
 -aes-128-ecb              -aes-128-gcm              -aes-128-ofb            
 -aes-128-xts              -aes-192-cbc              -aes-192-cfb            
 -aes-192-cfb1             -aes-192-cfb8             -aes-192-ctr            
 -aes-192-ecb              -aes-192-gcm              -aes-192-ofb            
 -aes-256-cbc              -aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha1    -aes-256-cfb            
 -aes-256-cfb1             -aes-256-cfb8             -aes-256-ctr            
 -aes-256-ecb              -aes-256-gcm              -aes-256-ofb            
 -aes-256-xts              -aes128                   -aes192                  
 -aes256                   -bf                       -bf-cbc                  
 -bf-cfb                   -bf-ecb                   -bf-ofb                  
 -blowfish                 -camellia-128-cbc         -camellia-128-cfb        
 -camellia-128-cfb1        -camellia-128-cfb8        -camellia-128-ecb        
 -camellia-128-ofb         -camellia-192-cbc         -camellia-192-cfb        
 -camellia-192-cfb1        -camellia-192-cfb8        -camellia-192-ecb        
 -camellia-192-ofb         -camellia-256-cbc         -camellia-256-cfb        
 -camellia-256-cfb1        -camellia-256-cfb8        -camellia-256-ecb        
 -camellia-256-ofb         -camellia128              -camellia192            
 -camellia256              -cast                     -cast-cbc                
 -cast5-cbc                -cast5-cfb                -cast5-ecb              
 -cast5-ofb                -chacha                   -des                    
 -des-cbc                  -des-cfb                  -des-cfb1                
 -des-cfb8                 -des-ecb                  -des-ede                
 -des-ede-cbc              -des-ede-cfb              -des-ede-ofb            
 -des-ede3                 -des-ede3-cbc             -des-ede3-cfb            
 -des-ede3-cfb1            -des-ede3-cfb8            -des-ede3-ofb            
 -des-ofb                  -des3                     -desx                    
 -desx-cbc                 -gost89                   -gost89-cnt              
 -gost89-ecb               -id-aes128-GCM            -id-aes192-GCM          
 -id-aes256-GCM            -rc2                      -rc2-40-cbc              
 -rc2-64-cbc               -rc2-cbc                  -rc2-cfb                
 -rc2-ecb                  -rc2-ofb                  -rc4                    
 -rc4-40                   -rc4-hmac-md5            


What does openssl version print on the two systems? (Please add that information to the question.)

For all it's worth: I can't replicate this on Sonoma. Not with the system SSL LibreSSL 3.3.6 nor w/  OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024 installed via brew.

Re:  Versions: On OSX:  LibreSSL 2.6.5, on Linux: OpenSSL 3.0.11.  Is this just a version issue?

According to the usage message, the macOS version doesn't support -pbkdf2 or -iter.

@Emily your SSL is going to be six years old next month; there have been 6 versions released in the 2.x branch since then, 3.x appeared in Jan 2019 ... it might be time for you to upgrade. Which MacOS release are you on?

man pages and documentation for open_ssl will tell you everything you need to know.
